# iceprog - Can't find iCE FTDI USB device

Tags: linux, yosys

I'm trying to upload a bitstream file to iCEblink40-LP1K Evaluation Kit with `iceprog` on Arch Linux.

```
sudo iceprog setbit.bin
```

Then it complains:

```
Can't find iCE FTDI USB device (vedor_id 0x0403, device_id 0x6010).
```

And `lsusb` shows only:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 1443:0007 Digilent Development board JTAG
```

Here is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 5591.903500] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATES**

I tried:

```
modprobe ftdi_sio
echo 0403 6010 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
```

and

```
echo 1443 0007 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
sudo iceprog -d i:0x1443:0x0007 setbit.bin
```

But it still not working.

I also found someone said that different devices can be connect with different clock frequency.
https://tingcao.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/install-xilinx-cable-drivers-on-32-bit-ubuntu/#attachment_272

Answer (score 5):

The iCEblink40 board does *not* use an FTDI-based programming circuit and can therefore not be programmed with `iceprog`. Use `iceBurn` instead: https://github.com/davidcarne/iceBurn (This tool is also linked to from the [Project IceStorm website](http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/).)

See also the [`examples/iceblink/`](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/icestorm/tree/master/examples/iceblink) directory in the icestorm git repository for a complete example for the iceblink board. (This example is for the iCEblink40-HX1K board, not the iCEblink40-LP1K board. So it won't work out of the box because the FPGA pin assignments are different for the two boards. But the programming bit in the Makefile should be the same for the two types of boards.)